# How do I generate two number so that the result of division is an integer?

Tags: java

I am trying to generate two numbers so that the division result is an integer, not a double, for example: 2/2=1; 30/3=10; etc... I do not want something like this: 14/5=2.8; 18/7=2.57..etc.  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

```
package number;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class IntergerNumber extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JLabel lblFirstNum = new JLabel("");
JLabel lblSecondNum = new JLabel("");
JLabel lblOperator = new JLabel("/");
JTextArea taResult = new JTextArea();
JButton bCheck = new JButton("Check");
JPanel pOperator = new JPanel();
JPanel pButton = new JPanel();

public IntergerNumber()
{
pOperator.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
pOperator.add(new JLabel());
pOperator.add(lblFirstNum);
pOperator.add(lblOperator);
pOperator.add(lblSecondNum);
pOperator.add(new JLabel());
pOperator.add(taResult);
pButton.add(bCheck);
initializeComponents();
generateRanDomNumber();
this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.getContentPane().add(pOperator, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.getContentPane().add(pButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private void generateRanDomNumber() 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt2 = 0;
int randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
if(randomInt1 == 0)
{
randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
}
while((randomInt1%2) != 0) //this will avoid odd number
{
randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%2;
if(randomInt1 == 0)
{
randomInt1 = randomInt1 + 2;
}
}
randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%2;
if(randomInt2 == 0)
{
randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
}
while((randomInt2%2) != 0)
{
randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%2;
if(randomInt2 == 0)
{
randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
}
}

if(randomInt1 >= randomInt2 && randomInt2 != 0)
{               
System.out.println("====================");
System.out.println("First number is: " + randomInt1);
System.out.println("Second number is: " + randomInt2);
double x = randomInt1/randomInt2;
System.out.println("X is: " + x);
System.out.println("====================");
lblFirstNum.setText("" + randomInt1);
lblSecondNum.setText("" + randomInt2);
}
else if(randomInt1 < randomInt2 && randomInt1 != 0)
{               
System.out.println("====================");
System.out.println("First number is: " + randomInt1);
System.out.println("Second number is: " + randomInt2);
double x = randomInt2/randomInt1;
System.out.println("X is: " + x);
System.out.println("====================");
lblFirstNum.setText("" + randomInt2);
lblSecondNum.setText("" + randomInt1);
}
}

private void initializeComponents() 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
lblOperator.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
lblOperator.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
taResult.setBackground(Color.white);
taResult.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
taResult.setOpaque(true);       
lblFirstNum.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
lblFirstNum.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
lblSecondNum.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
lblSecondNum.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
bCheck.addActionListener(this);
taResult.setFocusable(true);
taResult.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(ae.getSource().equals(bCheck))
{
String sFirstNum = lblFirstNum.getText();
String sSecondNum = lblSecondNum.getText();
String sResult = taResult.getText();
int first = Integer.parseInt(sFirstNum);
int second = Integer.parseInt(sSecondNum);
int result = Integer.parseInt(sResult);
if((first/second) == result)
{
System.out.println("Correct Answer");
taResult.setText("");
generateRanDomNumber();
taResult.setFocusable(true);
taResult.requestFocus();
}
else
{
System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
taResult.setText("");
generateRanDomNumber();
taResult.setFocusable(true);
taResult.requestFocus();
}
}
}
public static void main(String[] s)
{
IntergerNumber in = new IntergerNumber();
in.setVisible(true);
in.setSize(200,200);
in.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: How are you generating at the moment? What are the constraints?

Comment: `a%b == 0` is one way to check

Answer (score 6):

You just multiply two numbers together: a*b=c - then you have c, so that when it is divided by a or b, it is an integer?

Answer (score 2):

as suggested by @chris:
here is what you can do:

**Edit:**

```
// `+1` as random number generated can be "0" which will result in `ArithmeticException`
int num1 = Random.nextInt(100)+1;  // enter range as required

int num2 = Random.nextInt(100)+1;

int divident = num1*num2;  // here is your first number
```

now choose any variable `num1` or `num2` as your second number as `divident%num1 == 0` or `divident%num2==0`

Its lot better than keep on testing random numbers until they meet this criteria `num1%num2==0`

Comment: +1, you might want to +1 on the random numbers. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey oh yeah! Good catch, now edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it works for your logic

```
int randomInt2 = 0;
int randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
if(randomInt1 == 0){
   randomInt1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
}
ramdonInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
while((randomInt1 < randomInt2) && (randomInt1%randomInt2 != 0)){
  randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)%20;
}
```

And now now you can directly put your remaining logic wihtout any `if-else`

```
System.out.println("====================");
System.out.println("First number is: " + randomInt1);
System.out.println("Second number is: " + randomInt2);
double x = randomInt2/randomInt1;
System.out.println("X is: " + x);
System.out.println("====================");
lblFirstNum.setText("" + randomInt2);
lblSecondNum.setText("" + randomInt1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void generateNumbers() {
 while(true) {
   int number1 = Random.nextInt(100);
   int number2 = Random.nextInt(100);
   if (number1 % number2 == 0) {
     System.out.println("Number " + number1 + " is divisible by " + number2);
     break;
   }
}
```

You could write something like this. It generates two random integers within 100. You could change the range of integers to suit your needs. The rule is to simply choose the integers such that the division of one by the other doesn't result in a remainder. Note this code isn't tested. Hope you get the idea.